# I want to make page with fixed content and scroll background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, web-frontend

Hello I want to make page with fixed content and scroll background like this side http://hellomonday.com/ how to make it?

Comment: Check the `view source` of that site and try to mimic the same ;-)

Comment: It's possible to do it just with CSS. Check this: https://codyhouse.co/gem/alternate-fixed-scroll-backgrounds/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "position" attribute and set it to "fixed".
Here is an example.

```html
<div  style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid; overflow:scroll;">
  <div style = "width:180px; height:50px; border: 1px solid; position:fixed;">
    abc
  </div>

  <div style = "width: 180px; height:250px; border: 1px solid; margin-top:60px;">
    123
  </div>
</div>
```